# Check Whether the purchase ID exist in v-data table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to check the purchase ID whether exist from the v-data table, if not exists then will display alert message. But I have got the errors.
So i apply the checking method which is **tick()** into v-btn, once the user clicked the button, it will check the existence of purchase ID, if the ID exist then add to "selected" column, if not exist then unable to add.

```
<template lang="html">
<div class="">
<input
hidden
type="file"
accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.pdf"
ref="selectPic"
@change="addReceipt"
>
<v-btn @click="selectPic()" color="info">Select Image</v-btn><br>
<img :src="preview" alt=""><br>
<input type="text" name="test" v-model="text" placeholder="type here" /><v-btn @click="tick()"small color="rgba(10,0,0,0)">click</v-btn><br>
<v-btn @click="submit()" v-if="preview" :disabled="selected.length==0" x-small color="rgba()">Confirm</v-btn><br>
<p>Total : {{sum}}</p>
<p>Purchase Ids: {{selected}}</p>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Purchase ID</th>
  <th>Merchant</th>
  <th>Review Date</th>
  <th>Order ID</th>
  <th>Payment Method</th>
  <th>Order Total</th>
  <th>Purchase Amount</th>
  <th>Amount Pay</th>
  <th>Tick</th>
</tr>
<tr v-for="(p,i) in purchases">
  <td @click="selectList(p.purchase_id,p.amountDue)">{{p.purchase_id}} <span v-if="p.old_purchase_id">&nbsp;({{p.old_purchase_id}})</span></td>
  <td @click="selectList(p.purchase_id,p.amountDue)">{{p.shop_name}}</td>
  <td @click="selectList(p.purchase_id,p.amountDue)">{{p.reviewedDate.split(" ")[0]}}</td>
  <td @click="selectList(p.purchase_id,p.amountDue)">{{p.order_id}}</td>
  <td @click="selectList(p.purchase_id,p.amountDue)">
    <div v-if="p.payment_method!='redemption'">
      {{p.redemptions}} <br>
      {{p.payment_method}}: {{p.orderCurrency}} {{p.payment}}
    </div>
    <div v-if="p.payment_method=='redemption'">
      {{p.redemptions}}
    </div>
  </td>
  <td @click="selectList(p.purchase_id,p.amountDue)">{{p.orderCurrency}} {{p.amount}}</td>
  <td @click="selectList(p.purchase_id,p.amountDue)">{{p.currency_code}} {{p.total}}</td>
  <td @click="selectList(p.purchase_id,p.amountDue)">{{p.currency_code}} {{p.amountDue}}</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" :value="p.purchase_id" v-model="selected" :ref="'selectList'+p.purchase_id" @change="handleSum($event.target.checked,p.amountDue)"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</template>
```

Script code:

```
<script>
export default {
data(){
return{
  preview: null,
  purchases: [],
  selected: [],
  text:'',
  sum: 0,
  count: 0,
  exists: null
 }
},
created(){
  this.getPurchases()
},
methods:{
  submit(){
  axios.post("/api/admin/order/uploadPaySlip",{
    selected: this.selected,
    image: this.preview
  }).then(response => {
    location.reload()
  })
 },
 getPurchases(){
  this.$store.state.loading = true
  axios.get("/api/admin/order/getPurchases?status=2"
  ).then(response => {
    this.purchases = response.data.labels
    this.$store.state.loading = false
  })
},
selectPic(){
  var btn = this.$refs.selectPic
  btn.click()
},
selectList(p,sum){
  let cb = this.$refs['selectList'+p]
  cb[0].click()
  this.handleSum(cb[0].checked,sum);
},
addReceipt(e){
  let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  if (!files.length)
      return;

  let file = files[0];

  let reader = new FileReader();
  let vm = this;
  reader.onload = (e) => {
      vm.preview = e.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},
tick(){
    var array = this.text.split(" ");
    array.forEach((item, index)=>{
      if(array.indexOf(this.purchase_id) !== -1){
        this.selected.push(parseInt(item))
        console.log('true');
      }else{
        alert(this.$translate('ID_not_exist'))
      }

    })

    this.text = '';
},
handleSum(state,sum){
    // Add or deduct total sum of payment slips
    if(!state) this.sum -= parseFloat(sum)
    else this.sum += parseFloat(sum)

    // Handle floating numbers
    if(this.selected.length == 0) this.sum = 0;
 }
 }
}
</script>
```

What problem I faced is the tick() method, whether I enter the purchase ID that is exist, it keep show me error message and unable to add to the input text.

Anyone have idea to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: There's nowhere in your code that has `some` being used (I suspect it is in the `this.checkIfIDExists()` method), which is indicated in your error message. Are you using `Array.prototype.some` on something that could potentially be undefined? Can you show us the logic for that method?

Comment: @Terry Sorry, just modified the question. sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: `this.index.some(...)` is the line throwing the error. What is `this.index`? It is not declared in your component data, so it will always be `undefined`.

Comment: @Terry Opps, I think i better post all code out instead of part by part. haha

Comment: Again, your error is that `this.purchase_id` is undefined. It's the same error, no need to post the entire code.

Comment: @Terry I have no idea how to deal with that purchase id.

Comment: Well, where is it coming from? There is no where in your code where you store `purchase_id` in your component. That's why it's undefined.

Comment: @Terry Its from database there

Comment: Even if it is coming from the DB you are **not storing it in the component**. Aka there is no `this.purchase_id = ...` in your code. Otherwise you need to clarify where that purchase ID is supposed to be inferred from.